# How can I change the MATLAB contour, continuous color scale to a color scale of buckets?

Tags: matlab, contour, contourf

Right now I have a gray scale contour where the lighter the color the higher the value and the darker the color the lower the value. However I want it to be more of a bucket scale, where all the values between say 0-20 appear red, 20-40 appear green, and 40-60 all blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `contourf` to plot your contours, just provide an extra argument with a list of values of the specific contour levels you want to plot:

```
contourf(x, y, z, [0, 20, 40, 60]);
```

Comment: Works, however the actual picture of the scale doesnt change to show that it is in buckets. not a huge deal though

Comment: If you're talking about the colorbar, that's a little harder to accomplish. This seems to do what you want, but I haven't tested it myself: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28073-use-of-discrete-colors-in-contourf-and-pcolor-with-colorbar